# Sequences in $\ell_1$ which converge in the weak*-topology (wrt $c_0$) but not weakly

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, examples-counterexamples, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

Consider $\ell_1$ as a dual of $c_0$. It is well known that there must exist sequences of elements in $\ell_1$ which converge in the weak*-topology (wrt $c_0$) but not weakly. Can one give an example (likely using ultrafilters / Banach limits) of such a sequence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sequence of natural unit vectors:  $e_n$ has $1$ in the $n$th place, zero elsewhere.  Show it converges to zero weak* but not weakly.  Knowing the dual of $\ell_1$ should help.